# Bootstrap Linked DateTimePicker - How to add time to second Picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using the Bootstrap DateTimePicker plugin and have 2 DateTimePickers added to my page.

I'd like to add an hour and a half to the second picker based on the first picker's selection. In looking at the examples on the docs page, I started with their "Linked Pickers" code and attempting to modify. I can easily set the second picker's minDate to the first picker's selection, but I'm not sure how to "add" the time to the second picker and make it the default value.

My current code for the minDate is:

```
$("#dtpFrom").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#dtpTo').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this worked out using Moment.js which was already a pre-req for the Bootstrap DateTimePicker.

For future googlers, here is what I came up with:

```
var dtpTo = moment(e.date);
var newTime = dtpTo.add(90, 'minutes');
$('#dtpTo').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date); // Minimum Constraint
$('#dtpTo').data("DateTimePicker").date(newTime); // Sets Value
```